# Who was worse: Lavan, Pharaoh or Haman?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, haman

In the hagadah we seem to indicate that Lavan was a worse enemy of the Jewish people because Pharaoh only decreed against the males while Lavan sought to uproot all. Based on this logic it would seem that Haman too is worse than Pharaoh for he also sought to uproot all (and perhaps worse than Lavan for he sought to kill many more people). **However** in practice the only one who actually killed any Jews at all (as far as I know) was Pharaoh, which I think would make a strong case for him being the worst.

Is there a source which definitively states which of these three people was the worst enemy of the Jews?

Comment: Isn't the Hagada such a source?

Comment: @IsaacMoses not of the 3. frankly i doubt there is

Comment: This is similar to the more contemporary question of who was worse for the Jews, hitler y"sh or stalin y"sh.  The former killed more Jews, but the latter had a far more devastating effect on the Jewish population.

Comment: Well, as for any Jews at all, there is an opinion that Haman killed Hasach after noticing him going between Esther and Mordechai.

Comment: I shall add to the question....why didn’t the hagada compare lavan,paroh and amalek

Comment: Hitler. Because he killed 6 million people.

Comment: I think Hitler, Amalek, Palestinian muslims, Haman, Stalin, Lavan, and Pharoah were all bad and all would have eradicated every Jew if they could do so. For the sake of the question tho, I think Haman was the worst enemy of the Jewish people. Although the Torah says that Amalek is an eternal enemy of Israel. One could argue that Amalek is a metaphor for all ant-semites.

Comment: I don't think it is important to rank them just because. They were each worse in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

the Divrei Esther...
Haman was worse than Paroh because he wanted to kill all צורר כל היהודים
he quotes [Esther Rabbah 7/23](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther_Rabbah.7.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that says Haman said my plan is best ...Paroh’s plan was limited to only males

I will say Lavan had no chance against Yaakov but Haman almost nailed all of them ..

Comment: Which Medrash 7/23?

Comment: אסתר רבה.  ז. כג.         כד